# Page exist but content is 404 error (want to use Selenium to get image)

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use Selenium webdriver to download image from [this site](http://covid-19.moh.gov.my/terkini/2021/06/situasi-terkini-covid-19-di-malaysia-24062021)

each day there is a new page created, on this new page, images will be uploaded to it around 6 pm.

```
url = 'http://covid-19.moh.gov.my/terkini/2021/06/situasi-terkini-covid-19-di-malaysia-24062021'
driver.get(url)
images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')

for image in images:
  print(image.get_attribute('src'))
```

when i run the code, even when no images are seen in regular browser (before 6pm), using selenium i still can get a list of those image urls,

```
# sample output from code
http://covid-19.moh.gov.my/terkini/2021/06/situasi-terkini-covid-19-di-malaysia-24062021/ukk-KlusterBaruHarian9.jpg
http://covid-19.moh.gov.my/terkini/2021/06/situasi-terkini-covid-19-di-malaysia-24062021/ukk-KlusterBaruHarian10.jpg
http://covid-19.moh.gov.my/terkini/2021/06/situasi-terkini-covid-19-di-malaysia-24062021/statskluster01.jpg
http://covid-19.moh.gov.my/terkini/2021/06/situasi-terkini-covid-19-di-malaysia-24062021/statskluster02.jpg
http://covid-19.moh.gov.my/terkini/2021/06/situasi-terkini-covid-19-di-malaysia-24062021/statskluster03.jpg
http://covid-19.moh.gov.my/terkini/2021/06/situasi-terkini-covid-19-di-malaysia-24062021/taburankes-all.jpg
```

the img url exist but the image seems to come up as 404 error.
[image]

I can even use wget on the img url to download, but the result is an empty/corrupted img

can someone explain to me these behaviours (I have no web development knowledge) and how to bypass it? I only want to download the image when only it is really there.

Comment: Try to call the page with headers like user agent

Comment: the page is loading dynamically, and images are frequently being deleted by website owner company

Answer (score 0):

2 issues here:

1. the URL you are using is loading very slowly or even not loaded at all, this is why you getting the **Error 404**
2. You have to put wait / delay before performing `images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')` to let the page load completely.
   **UPD**
   if the error 404 appears after clicking a link on the web page it means that the link is broken or there is some other server side issue. It is not caused by wrong Selenium code. Just some problems with that web site.

Comment: I believe it is loaded fully. Error 404 is when I enter the img url itself. On the webpage, no image is seen in regular browser, but using selenium I can get the list of img urls, which they themselves are actually empty/404

Comment: If so the link is broken. Anyway this is a server side issue.

Comment: how to bypass it?

Comment: To tell the developers of that web site to fix their bugs. It's not caused by you